# How can I import a csv with special characters using csvsimple?

Tags: csvsimple

I am quite new to LaTeX so apologies if this is very basic. I have a micro (µ) symbol in a csv file header that I want to import. This code I am using is:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{This is the caption for the first table}
\centering
\csvautobooktabular{tables/PDX_metadata.csv}
\end{table}
```

This constantly gives an error when knitting... Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `\csvautotabular[respect all]{PDX_metadata.csv}`

Comment: This also doesn't work unfortunately.. It works with special characters in the table but if I include one in the header it throws an error...

Comment: I have no problem with: `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{filecontents*}{PDX_metadata.csv}
a,b,c
1,2,µ
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{This is the caption for the first table}
\centering
\csvautobooktabular{PDX_metadata.csv}
\end{table}
\end{document}` Is your TeX distribution updated?

Comment: Am I right in thinking in you example you haven't included the special character in the header? Its when the character is in the header that it does work.. have just tried with your code..

Comment: There was another solution you commented but seems to have disappeared?

Comment: Also this one works for me: `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{filecontents*}{PDX_metadata.csv}
a,b,µ
1,2,µ
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{This is the caption for the first table}
\centering
\csvautobooktabular{PDX_metadata.csv}
\end{table}
\end{document}`. The other solution didn't work.

Comment: This still doesn't work for me.. Does this get you an autobook formatted table with a special character in the header?

Comment: Yes, it does. See here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/zxqsfqpjxsvk

Comment: Sorted now, thanks very much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! You could post an answer to your own question with the solution, if you like, or delete your question.